# Update a label text GTK+ C++

Tags: c++, gtk, label

Let's say I have created a gird:

```
grid = gtk_grid_new();
```

Then added a button with `"label"` as text:

```
button = gtk_button_new_with_label ("label");
```

And attached it to the grid:

```
gtk_grid_attach (GTK_GRID (grid), button, 0, 0, 1, 1);
gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (vbox), grid);
```

i got something, like following:

```
char c = 'e';
// And I want to update the label's text with the value stored in c.
```

How are we supposed to update a label's previously set text?

I'm new to GTK+, I think I should be sorry for this question... But here it is...

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a `GtkButton`, use `gtk_button_set_label()`. For a `GtkLabel`, use `gtk_label_set_text()`.

Note that you can't pass a `char` into these functions, as a single character is not a string. The comment by MrEricSir implies you were trying to read keyboard input from the console in your GUI program. So now I'm wondering specifically what you are trying to write... I understand if you're converting an existing command-line program to a GUI program, but be aware that this migration is too nontrivial to do piece by piece (if that's what you were doing).